# Why Setting DataPropertyName of datagridview do the job even after setting datasource?

Tags: c#, asp.net, datagridview

I Know this is a weird question but I can't figured it out why my code do what I want.

this is how I put my data in a `datagridview`

```
using (SqlConnection SqlCon = new SqlConnection(StrCon))
    {
        SqlCon.Open();

        using (SqlCommand SqlCmd = new SqlCommand())
        {
            SqlCmd.Connection = SqlCon;
            SqlCmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

            SqlCmd.CommandText = "SelectWe...";

            SqlCmd.Parameters.Add("@HiveNumber", SqlDbType.Int).Value = ...;
            SqlCmd.Parameters.Add("@RV", SqlDbType.Int).Direction = ...;

            DataTable Dtable = new DataTable();

            Dtable.Load(SqlCmd.ExecuteReader());


            WeeklyRptdgv.Columns[0].DataPropertyName = "RecID";

            WeeklyRptdgv.Columns[2].DataPropertyName = "VisitDate";

            WeeklyRptdgv.Columns[3].Name = "QueenExists";
            WeeklyRptdgv.Columns[3].DataPropertyName = "QueenExists";

            WeeklyRptdgv.Columns[4].Name = "QueenVisited";
            WeeklyRptdgv.Columns[4].DataPropertyName = "QueenVisited";

            WeeklyRptdgv.Columns[5].Name = "QueenCellVisited";
            WeeklyRptdgv.Columns[5].DataPropertyName = "QueenCellVisited";

            WeeklyRptdgv.Columns[6].DataPropertyName = "HoneyStatus";

            WeeklyRptdgv.Columns[7].DataPropertyName = "EggLayingStatus";

            WeeklyRptdgv.DataSource = Dtable;
```

until here it's okay, but the column number of 3,4,5 are bool and I want them to displayed in `CheckBox` not a true/false.

so I do this after setting data source:

```
using (SqlConnection SqlCon = new SqlConnection(StrCon))
    {
        SqlCon.Open();

        using (SqlCommand SqlCmd = new SqlCommand())
        {
            ...

            WeeklyRptdgv.DataSource = Dtable;

            WeeklyRptdgv.Columns.Remove("QueenExists");
            DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn QueenExists = new DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn();
            QueenExists.Name = "QueenExists";
            QueenExists.DataPropertyName = "QueenExists";
            WeeklyRptdgv.Columns.Insert(3, QueenExists);

            WeeklyRptdgv.Columns.Remove("QueenVisited");
            DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn QueenVisited = new DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn();
            QueenVisited.Name = "QueenVisited";
            QueenVisited.DataPropertyName = "QueenVisited";
            WeeklyRptdgv.Columns.Insert(4, QueenVisited);

            WeeklyRptdgv.Columns.Remove("QueenCellVisited");
            DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn QueenCellVisited = new DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn();
            QueenCellVisited.Name = "QueenCellVisited";
            QueenCellVisited.DataPropertyName = "QueenCellVisited";
            WeeklyRptdgv.Columns.Insert(5, QueenCellVisited);

            }
        }
```

this code do what I want but I cant find out how the columns get their values after the original one is removed

or maybe this solution is wrong and I'm not aware of that.

Comment: Can you share how you have declared datagridview in the aspx page? Does it have AutoGenerateColumn set to true or false?

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya I set it to false by code

Comment: Then you should add checkbox columns and other column in aspx only and set DataPropertyName there. IN Code behind only datasource of the datagridview should be set.

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya I don't know how to do that so I had to do it this way :(

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong... I am assuming that you are developing web application... Also can you share where databinding code block is written, in form_load?

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya no it's windows form application, No it's in ComboBox_SelectedIndexChanged

Comment: And you are not able to get the values from the columns which you inserted at position 3,4 and 5 ?

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya I get them in a true/false way, I want them to shown like a checkbox and by this way i get what i want

Comment: cool.... are you facing any other issue or looking for any more information?

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya I want to know if this way has any problem or what's the better way

Comment: Please go thru the answer I posted below.

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya Tanks a lot for your time,
it helped.
because this datagrid had to get another type of data by clicking another button I had to write this codes, But after your answer I most consider creating different dgv for it's own purpose to avoid this kind of problem, tanks again

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am sure that you are well aware about how to add columns to datagridview at design time.

While adding columns at design time you need to select proper column type such as DataGridViewTextBoxColumn, DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn, DataGridViewButtonColumn etc.

Once you have added columns properly in datagridview at design time, only thing which is pending is set the DataPropertyName for all the columns and set DataSource of the DataGridView.

You are doing all these things except the selecting correct ColumnType for checkbox columns when you are adding columns at design time.[image]